# Where operator too slow after joins

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql

I have a query which joins 4 tables and then I use `where` clause to find matching rows.

But after the joins the where is too slow. It adds about 30 seconds.

Controller:

```
@offers = Offer.select("offers.*, categories.name as cat_name, states.name as s_name, cities.name as c_name")
                    .joins("LEFT JOIN categories ON categories.id = offers.category_id")
                    .joins("LEFT JOIN states ON states.id = offers.state_id")
                    .joins("LEFT JOIN cities ON cities.id = offers.city_id")
                    .where("states.name = ? OR cities.name = ? and date BETWEEN ? and ?",
                            params[:search], params[:search], params[:date_start], params[:date_end])
                    .order(:date)
                    .paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 10)
```

Is there a way of creating indexes or speeding up the query?

Comment: Using WHERE on tables that are part of LEFT JOIN makes it the same as INNER JOIN

Comment: Are there indexes on state_id and city_id in offers and on name in states and cities?

Comment: Yes I have, @LukaszSzozda thanks for the tip. It was really helpful.

Comment: When asking about the performance of a query, please always add the output of `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS) SELECT ...` and also tell us how many rows exist in each involved table at least. Best would also be to all `CREATE TABLE` and `CREATE INDEX` statements here, so any answer goes beyond of just guessing.